# Up-to-date values of Yukawa couplings (2023)

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, interactions, data

Where can I find the most recent values for the Yukawa couplings in 2023? I currently have access to the values from 2011, but I guess precision has improved over the last decade in measurements.

Edit:

I am interested in the raw values.

Comment: See the Higgs couplings section of https://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?node=S126&init=0

Comment: @Andrew I have checked the website, but I find the top quark Yukawa coupling to be around 0.95 and the bottom quark Yukawa coupling to be around 0.90. This is not correct, since the top quark Yukawa coupling is much bigger than any other Yukawa coupling. I am wrong at interpreting the data in pdglive?

Comment: You are misreading them! the κ s are ratios of measured over SM-theoretical!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Then where can I find a list of the precise values?

Comment: The κs, as noted, are defined in [here](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-higgs-boson.pdf),  and  specify by how much the coupling of the Higgs boson to a given particle deviates from the SM expectation, $y=\sqrt{2} m/v$, where v=246GeV. So they are perforce all close to 1. You may trivially throw these in all tables of that review provided. Looks like, in practice, they are mostly below 1. You want an answer exemplifying this?

Comment: Thanks @CosmasZachos I think I can work out a table with SM expectation values and then corrected them with ks, but I thought someone must already have done this, right? How is that there is not a list of Yukawa coupling values published anywhere?

Comment: Ach, the experiments measure those, in the first place, but present them in a "friendly"  κ-ratio form making new physics, or tension with the SM,  evident. Nobody, except you, could be interested in the raw numbers.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Research in fundamental constants in physics is interested in raw values: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5256069/ (2011)

Comment: Ah... but in this particular field, dominated deeply by the SM, raw values are actually uninteresting if they agree with the SM. They are desperately hunting for deviations therefrom! And the yukawas are aggressively, spitefully, sporadic and non-fundamental....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(11.32) of [this pdg overview](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-higgs-boson.pdf) defines the ratio parameter $\kappa_t=y_t v/m_t$ as the quantity you are seeking in units of the SM expectation in each case/flavor.

So, for example, the measured top yukawa is, e.g. for [ATLAS 2022](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-022-04893-w),
$$
y_t\equiv \kappa_t m_t/v= 0.95\cdot \frac{172.8}{246}\approx 0.67,
$$
[etc](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/DataBlock.action?node=S126YTC).

Even though most κs are around 1 for each flavor, indicating the SM works pretty well, the corresponding yukawas scale up as the quark masses.

---

*Edit in response to comments*

If you are looking for the formal constant $h_t= y_t \sqrt{2}= 0.95$ defined in (11.3)-(11.6) of the review cited, which is closer to 1, you may retain the silly $\sqrt{2}$ and call $h_t$ the Yukawa coupling. It is purely a matter of normalization. What I am using in the main answer is the actual coupling $y_t$ of the quark to the Higgs scalar *H*, as specified in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction#Yukawa_coupling_to_the_Higgs_in_the_Standard_Model). These dimensionless constants are mere inputs to the SM, but their origin in an over-arching fundamental theory, perhaps at GUT scales,  remains a mystery.

Comment: Isn't there a square root of 2 missing in the calculation of the Yukawa couplings?

Comment: Why isn't the top quark Yukawa coupling almost 1?

Comment: See edit to answer: sheer trivial convention. It would help if you indicated or suggested ***why*** you 'd be interested in these values in the first place.

Comment: I am studying the fundemental constants of nature, and I want to study Yukawa couplings in the most natural and fundamental values.

Comment: Not even when measured at low energies and portraited in a non-dimensional way?

Comment: You mean not fundamental there? At low energies they are particularly capricious, as having evolved down from higher energies where they ***might***, just might, have their origin. They are always non-dimensional, but how they link up to a mysterious mass matrix and the generation structure is a mystery, whatever pretentious perforators might like to bloviate up...